# sectioned table view animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I see this quite often, where you have sections view on top and then when you scroll up and the next section view reaches/overlap with the section view on top then it merges. How do I do something like this? Is there a library for doing this?

Comment: Are you referring to the behavior you see in the Contacts app?

Comment: Yes! Where the Alphabet scrolls up

Comment: That sounds like the default behavior for a UITableView as sections, in which case you don't have to to anything. Can you point to an example that illustrates the type of animation you're seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behavior supported by all UITableViews (you don't need a custom library for this). You have to implement the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView method of your UITableView:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
}
```